# Sorting order in elastica ruflin for Elasticsearch

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I am using "Elastica: elasticsearch PHP Client" from https://github.com/ruflin/Elastica and
I cant use order "ASC"/"DESC" when creating a query like this:

```
$elasticaQueryString  = new \Elastica\Query\QueryString();
$elasticaQueryString->setQuery('search_word');

$elasticaQuery = new \Elastica\Query();
$elasticaQuery->setQuery($elasticaQueryString);
$elasticaQuery->setSort("id");

$elasticaResultSet    = $elasticaIndex->search($elasticaQuery);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turned out I need to use an array like this

> $elasticaQuery->setSort(array("id" => "asc"));